# set maximum imagesize for django Photologue

Tags: django, photologue

just uploaded some photos via django photologue. And one image, an extreme panorama format will not show properly. its 2200px wide. 
Is there a limitation to the size of an image and can this limitation be changed?
thx

Answer (score 0):

Photologue comes with a PhotoSize model, that allows you to crop or resize the uploaded image to a set of pre-configured sizes. You can manage the PhotoSizes from the admin console.
I think you want to use the upscale option to True.

http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/PhotoSize